# Question regarding the force exerted by a water pressure wave against a barrier

Tags: forces, waves, pressure, acoustics

I'm having some trouble reconciling what I believe should be two valid strategies to solve the following problem:

> Water flows at $7.0\, \text{m}/\text{s}$ in a pipe of radius $5.0\, \text{cm}$. A plate with area equal to the cross-sectional area of the pipe is suddenly inserted to stop the flow. Find the force exerted on the plate. Take the speed of sound in water to be $1.4\, \text{km}/\text{s}$. *Hint: When the plate is inserted, a pressure wave propagates through the water at the speed of sound, $v_\text{s}$. The mass of water brought to a stop in time $\Delta t$ is the water in a length of pipe
>   equal to $v_\text{s}\, \Delta t$.*

The correct answer is $77\,\text{kN}$, which can be found by $$F\approx F_\text{av}=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}=\frac{\Delta(mv)}{\Delta t}=\frac{m\,\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$ The mass $m$ being considered is equal to $$m=\rho_\text{w}V=\rho_\text{w}A\ell=\rho_\text{w}(\pi r^2) (v_\text{s}\,\Delta t)$$
where $\rho_\text{s}$ is the volume mass density of water. Because the water in the pipe (which is initially traveling at a speed $v_\text{w}=7.0\, \text{m}/\text{s}$) is brought to a halt by the plate, we have $$\frac{m\,\Delta v}{\Delta t}=\frac{(\pi\rho_\text{w}r^2 v_\text{w}\,\Delta t)v_\text{s}}{\Delta t}=\pi\rho_\text{w}r^2 v_\text{s}v_\text{w}$$ $$=\pi(1000\,\text{kg}/\text{m}^3)(5.0\times10^{-2}\,\text{m})^2(1.4\times 10^3\, \text{m}/\text{s})(7.0\, \text{m}/\text{s})=77\times 10^3\,\text{N}=77\,\text{kN}$$ I'm wondering it it is also possible to approach this problem using the average energy density of a sound wave: $$\eta_\text{av}=\frac{\Delta E_\text{av}}{\Delta V}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{p_0^2}{\rho v^2}$$ where $p_0$ is the pressure amplitude of the wave (the maximum pressure effected by the wave), $\rho$ is the equilibrium density of the medium, and $v$ is the speed of propagation of the wave. Here is my attempt at a solution using this method.

In the equation for the average energy density, $\rho=\rho_\text{w}$ and $v=v_\text{s}$. The average power delivered by the pressure wave is $$P_\text{av}=\frac{(\Delta E)_\text{av}}{\Delta t}=\frac{\eta_\text{av}\,\Delta V}{\Delta t}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{p_0^2}{\rho_\text{w} v_\text{s}^2}A\ell}{\Delta t}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{p_0^2}{\rho_\text{w} v_\text{s}^2}Av_\text{s}\,\Delta t}{\Delta t}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{p_0^2A}{\rho_\text{w} v_\text{s}}$$At this point, I start making some pretty bold assumptions. Taking $P_\text{av}=(\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}_\text{w})_\text{av}=F_\text{av}v_\text{w}$ and $p_0=F_\text{max}/A=\sqrt{2}F_\text{av}/A$ gives $$P_\text{av}=F_\text{av}v_\text{w}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}F_\text{av}}{A}\right)^2A}{\rho_\text{w} v_\text{s}}=\frac{F_\text{av}^2}{\rho_\text{w} v_\text{s}A}=\frac{F_\text{av}^2}{\rho_\text{w} v_\text{s}\pi r^2}$$which simplifies to$$F_\text{av}=\pi\rho_\text{w}r^2 v_\text{s}v_\text{w}$$as before. This could very well be a completely invalid way to arrive at this result—I'll admit that I chose the maximum and average forces delivered by the pressure wave to be related by $F_\text{max}=\sqrt{2}F_\text{av}$ in order to make the math work, so I'm not sure if this is correct. (I can see why it might be, since the pressure varies sinusoidally with time, but I am incapable of proving it on my own.) I'm also a little confused as to whether or not the water does work on the plate (since it doesn't seem that the plate undergoes a displacement due to the force exerted on it) and if the relationship $P=\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ holds in this situation. If it does, I can see that $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}=Fv$, and the speed $v$ must be the speed of the water $v_\text{w}$, otherwise the solution would be incorrect.

Can anyone help to validate or reject this second (questionable) method to solve the problem? I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Questions asking for help with problem solving are *off topic* for this site. However if you narrowed down your question to the conceptual issues in your main paragraph this could be acceptable.